# How to inject $rootScope into Factory Function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

I've been given some AngularJS code that has a factory function that is called from a Directive that Posts a file to Web API.  I'm having trouble passing the key that is returned to my controller.  Can someone tell me how I can do this?

Here is my factory function that posts my file:

```
return fileManagerClient.save(formData)
  .$promise
  .then(function(result) {
      if (result && result.files) {
        result.files.forEach(function(file) {
          if (!fileExists(file.name)) {
            service.files.push(file);
          }
        });
      }

      appInfo.setInfo({
        message: "files uploaded successfully"
      });

      return result.$promise;
    },
    function(result) {
      appInfo.setInfo({
        message: "something went wrong: " + result.data.message
      });
      return $q.reject(result);
    })['finally'](
    function() {
      appInfo.setInfo({
        busy: false
      });
      service.status.uploading = false;
    });
}
```

and I'm trying to get result.value (which is the key of the posted file) passed into my controller but I'm not sure how to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Pete

Comment: too many unknowns in code shown. `return result.$promise;` looks suspicious. Also no idea what you are doing inside directive

Answer (score 0):

If what you say is true, then you just need to have the `then` callback return `result.value`:

```
.then(function(result) {
  if (result && result.files) {
    result.files.forEach(function(file) {
      if (!fileExists(file.name)) {
        service.files.push(file);
      }
    });
  }

  appInfo.setInfo({
    message: "files uploaded successfully"
  });

  return result.value;
}
```

In your controller:

```
myFactory.myFactoryFunction(formData)
    .then(function (key) {
        console.log(key);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you JLRishe and charlietfl . . . I didn't create this code and the problem I'm having in this case is understanding the flow.  Essentially, after the file is successfully uploaded I don't understand where it returns to.  In this case, I have a controller that has a directive in it.  This directive has a template in it which calls the function "Upload" which is in a factory.  Then upload uses another function in a different factory to actually upload the file.

Comment: So I'm thinking the key questions are:  Where does this line of code: "return result.$promise;" return to?  And if I replace that line of code with this:  "return result.value;" would it make a difference in regards to where the code returns to?  You see it's not hitting any breakpoint in any of my controllers after a successful file upload . . . Pete